# How do I catch keyboard shortcuts for windows in Avalonia

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

When I open a dialogue (window) in Avalonia I'd like to close it with the <kbd>Esc</kbd> button. What is a (the canonical) way to implement this?

---

I have looked through the [documentation](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/input/hotkeys) and done the regular search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way to close a dialog window is different than registering keybindings.  The typical method of closing the dialog without action is to set the cancel button's IsCancel property to true. This will automatically intercept the escape key and route it to the button's click event or command binding.

If you do not have a Cancel button, then you will need to use keybindings as explained in other answers.

```cs
public void OnCancel(object? sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
  this.Close();
}
```

```xml
<Button Content="Cancel" Click="OnCancel" IsCancel="True"/>
```

Likewise, you can do the same for the confirmation button ("OK") using the IsDefault property, which intercept the Enter Key (or Ctrl + Enter if you are focused on a control that accepts the key, such as a multiline text box).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a workaround with KeyBindings.

This worked for me:

First give the window a name with **x:Name** attribute on the Window tag. I used ***ThisWindow***.

then in the axaml file add KeyBindings:

```
  <Window.KeyBindings>
    <KeyBinding Gesture="Escape" Command="{Binding CloseCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ThisWindow}" />
  </Window.KeyBindings>
```

I tested this in the MainWindow so here is my MainWindowViewModel.cs:

```
public RelayCommand<Window> CloseCommand { get; private set; }

public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    this.CloseCommand = new RelayCommand<Window>(this.CloseCommandFunc);
}

public void CloseCommandFunc(Window window)
{
    if (window != null)
    {
        window.Close();
    }
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I cannot tell if your solution or the one of @Tarazed to be the most correct one but I got the solution of @Tarazed to work so I grant it the bounty. I am just trying out Avalonia with an already existing project and I couldn't get `public RelayCommand<Window> CloseCommand { get; private set; }}` to work. `RelayCommand` did recognise a generic version. I might have a too old Avalonia. Or something else.